# How to generate monthly reports in an Azure Web app Service

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

In our `Azure App Service Web App`, we are using an `ASP.NET Web API` and `Azure SQL Server database` for our business needs. How can we  generate our weekly aggregate report from the database? **Note**: Report should be generated automatically on weekly basis and question is NOT about usage report or azure resources reports such as the one explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/automate-custom-reports). Rather we want to use Azure to  automate the process of generating our weekly financial reports?

Comment: I hope you realize your question is a little vague. Are you asking for a custom report or usage report? Please be very specific about your requirements and needs.

Comment: @MehdiIbrahim I've added more explanation.

Comment: Ok, so these are custom reports. How are they generated right now? Are you trying to automate the execution of a query, an operation or some executable?

Comment: @MehdiIbrahim Currently we doing it naively using third party tools that are cumbersome process. It would be great if both the generation and the automation of the execution can be done in Azure. But at least the automation of weekly execution in Azure will be a good start.

Comment: We need to understand what this process looks like before we can recommend a solution in Azure. Help us understand the technologies you are using and what the report generation process looks like .e.g., if you're using Crystal Reports are you generating snapshot reports once a week? Are the reports being generated from your OLTP database or a copy/dedicated reporting database?